# C++ Collections Class

Tags: c++

I'm self studying C++.
If you're making a `Class` which only has a member variable that is a collection of "X" objects, (whatever X may be) would having just a default constructor and a deconstructor be enough seems its purely dealing with a collection of objects? Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry should have been clearer. For a different example, if you have a class "Aclass" that has an int, a string and a vector of objects of another class, would you advise the "Aclass" class to have a constructor with parameters? ie `Aclass(int i, string s);` and do you need to have the vector in the constructor too? I'm a little confused. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "collection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "collection of 'x' objects" you mean "a standard container of 'x' objects", and by "enough" you mean "enough not to worry about resource management" then yes. Same goes for any well-written container made by you or a third-party.

This is also assuming your X objects are handling *their* resources correctly. And that they have semantics that are compatible with the container you're putting them in.

Edit

You don't need a constructor like that if you are OK having an object filled with default values for everything. I.e. empty containers, zeroed members (or was it uninitialized? -_-), etc.

You only really need a custom constructor if your object will be in an invalid state without one or if you want some sort of custom logic to run.

Answer (score 0):

You mean enough to handle memory correctly? Depends on the type `X`. For example, if you have a `vector<string>` data member, you don't have to do any manual memory management in your class.

Answer (score 0):

For class you may write your own constructor, which shows, how to construct inner objects, i.e

```
class A{
    string s;
    int x;
    A(string t):s(t), x(17){} // x is always 17 after construction
}
```

But if inner object is default-constructable, you may leave it's construction and it will be costruct by default.

```
A(int l):x(l){}
```

is equivalent to

```
A(int l):x(l), s(){}
```

(except for primitive types), that may contain trash by default

If you use default constructor of `A`, all inner objects will construct by default.

Answer (score 0):

If by `collection` you mean standard library classes, you would need copy ctor and assignment operator= overloaded.

std::map and std::set would reqire an additional comparison operator< overloaded.
std::unorderd_map and std::unordered_set would need a std::hash specialized for your type.

Answer (score 0):

Often you don't have to define a default constructor. The compiler will declare a default constructor implicitly if one is needed and no constructors are defined. Often it will be useful to define additional constructors (like the one you mention) in addition to the default one. In that case you need to define both:

```
class A
{
public:

    string s;
    int x;

    // default constructor, no arguments
    A(): x(), s() {}

    // constructor
    A(int i, string t): x(i), s(t) {}
}

int main()
{
    A a1;
    A a2(5, "text");
    vector<A> ls;
    return 0;
}
```

As pwned mentions, in order to use your class A in an STL container, e.g. vector, it is required that A has a default constructor as in the example (either user-defined or implicit).